# Unable to see the name of items in my listbox, WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I was trying to get data from an observablecollection into my listbox, but instead of show the name of the item, I am getting Namespace.ItemClass (in my case, Retail_Items.RetailItem). I have attached an image. Where I might be wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7mjk.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please update your post to include the actual code you've tried, not just images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListBoxItem exposes the value bound to **ItemsSource** by default. 
And you probably bind a collection in the form of `List <RetailItem>`, so Namespace is printed out.

As with other people's answers, if the bound value is in the form of an object such as `RetailItem`, DisplayMemberPath can specify a specific property value as the output name.
This is because it dynamically creates `Binding` inside the ListBoxItem if DisplayMemberPath is present internally.

In fact, you can see the structure directly from the open source of the `.Net Framework`, which was published in Microsoft GitHub.

And I have distributed a sample source using ListBox/ListBoxItem's Style Template and MVVM structure to GITHub for you, so I hope it will help you.

[Sample Source](https://github.com/devncore/community/tree/main/stackoverflow/answers/listbox-binding-sample)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using a DataTemplate if you want to display multiple fields from your class or perhaps use the DisplayMemberPath property on the listbox to reference the relevant field.

Answer (score 0):

Set the DisplayMember property of the listBox to "Name" (if you want the Name property to show).

e.g.-

```
listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```